# How to put bootstrap tooltip on textbox if validation fails for that textbox?

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, tooltip

I want to Perform Validation on textbox if there is no value(empty).

I want to display Tooltip on textbox if validation fails.

This is my textbox:

```
<input type="text"  id="txtNo1" />
<input type="text"  id="txtNo2" />
<input type="text"  id="txtNo3" />

<input type="button" onclick="return ManipulateValue();">



function ManipulateValue() {
        var isValid = true;
         $('#txtNo1,#txtNo2,#txtNo3').each(function () {
            if ($.trim($(this).val()) == '') {
                isValid = false;
                $(this).css({
                    "border": "1px solid red",
                    "background": "#FFCECE"
                });
                $(this).tooltip('show'); //not working
            }
            else {
                $(this).css({
                    "border": "",
                    "background": ""
                });
                //$(this).tooltip('hide'); //not working
            }
        });
        if (isValid == false) {
            return false;
        }
       //ajax call to my controller method
     return true;
}
```

I have checked example of bootstrap tooltip and even tried it but it is not working.

So how to use bootstrap tooltip for validation of my textboxes??

Comment: give us a fiddle for better help..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a working example of how to do this with Bootstrap & jQuery but you should also [read](http://jqueryvalidation.org/) up how the validation can be put together because there are various methods; this Tooltip example is taken from [here](https://gist.github.com/johnnyreilly/5867188#file-demotooltip-html)

```js
$("#valForm").validate({

  showErrors: function(errorMap, errorList) {

    // Clean up any tooltips for valid elements
    $.each(this.validElements(), function(index, element) {
      var $element = $(element);

      $element.data("title", "") // Clear the title - there is no error associated anymore
        .removeClass("error")
        .tooltip("destroy");
    });

    // Create new tooltips for invalid elements
    $.each(errorList, function(index, error) {
      var $element = $(error.element);

      $element.tooltip("destroy") // Destroy any pre-existing tooltip so we can repopulate with new tooltip content
        .data("title", error.message)
        .addClass("error")
        .tooltip(); // Create a new tooltip based on the error messsage we just set in the title
    });
  },

  submitHandler: function(form) {
    alert("This is a valid form!");
  }
});

$('#reset').click(function() {
  var validator = $("#valForm").validate();
  validator.resetForm();
});
```

```css
body {
  background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.45);
}
.wrapper {
  padding-top: 75px;
}
#valForm input {
  width: 100%;
  height: 50px;
  padding: 5px 20px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  font-size: 16px;
}
#valForm select {
  width: 100%;
  padding: 5px 20px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  font-size: 16px;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  height: 50px;
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  -moz-appearance: none;
  appearance: none;
}
form#valForm {
  padding: 10px;
}
#valForm .error {
  border: 3px solid #b94a48 !important;
  background-color: #fee !important;
}
#valForm label {
  display: block;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  color: #1c1c1c;
}
#valForm .form-group {
  display: inline-block;
}
#valForm .btn-primary {
  width: 100%;
  height: 50px;
  border-radius: 0px;
  font-weight: 400;
  font-size: 25px;
  background: #70CCF4;
  border-color: #fff;
  margin-bottom: 15px;
}
#valForm .btn-clear {
  width: 100%;
  height: 50px;
  border-radius: 0px;
  font-weight: 400;
  font-size: 25px;
  background: #C91B08;
  border-color: #fff;
  color: #fff;
  margin-bottom: 15px;
}
#valForm .tooltip > .tooltip-inner {
  background-color: #f00;
}
#valForm .tooltip > .tooltip-arrow {
  border-top-color: #f00;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-validate/1.14.0/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="container">
    <form id="valForm" name="valForm">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-6">
          <input data-msg-date="A NAME is Required." data-msg-required="The NAME field is required." data-rule-text="true" data-rule-required="true" id="textField" name="textField" type="text" value="" />
          <label for="textField">A NAME is required.</label>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-6">
          <input data-msg-email="A Valid EMAIL is Required." data-msg-minlength="." data-msg-required="A Valid EMAIL is Required.." data-rule-email="true" data-rule-minlength="5" data-rule-required="true" id="emailField" name="emailField" type="text" value="" />
          <label for="emailField">A Valid EMail is Required.</label>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-6">
          <input data-msg-number="A NUMBER from 1-20 is Required." data-msg-range="A NUMBER from 1-20 is Required." data-rule-number="true" data-rule-range="[1,20]" id="numberField" name="numberField" type="text" value="0" />
          <label for="numberField">A Number between 1 and 20 is Required.</label>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-6">
          <select data-msg-required="One SELECTION is Required." data-rule-required="true" id="selectFIELD" name="selectFIELD">
            <option value="">Select Something</option>
            <option value="Yes">Option 1</option>
            <option value="No">Option 2</option>
            <option value="Maybe">Option 3</option>
          </select>
          <label for="selectFIELD">One Option is Required.</label>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-6">
          <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Validate</button>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-6">
          <input class="btn btn-clear" type="reset" id="reset" onClick="CommentForm.reset();" value="Clear Form" readonly>
        </div>
      </div>
    </form>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: i dont have any form tag in my code.so can you show me without using form tag??

Comment: Are you submitting a form?

Comment: no i am not submitting the form.its my division which i am posting through ajax

Comment: This snippet does not work

Answer (score 1):

at first you should include the [Bootstrap Tooltip plugin](http://www.tutorialrepublic.com/twitter-bootstrap-tutorial/bootstrap-tooltips.php) to call the *tooltip()*.

there is a direct plugin available for bootstrap,try with this [Bootstrap Validation Tooltip.](http://thrilleratplay.github.io/jquery-validation-bootstrap-tooltip/)

Comment: Can you please post solution with my code like what js will be use.i am using bootstrap.min.js and jquery